# Android ImaveView not wrap zoomed Image

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, android-imageview, scale

I have a ImageView inside a scrollable view.

```
<jp.vuph.TwoDScrollView
    android:id="@+id/two_d_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_drawing"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view_main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</jp.vuph.TwoDScrollView>
```

When I zoom the image, that ImageView doesn't warp all the zoomed image, so I can't see a part of it.This is my code

```
private class ScaleGestureListener implements ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        d = mImageViewMain.getDrawable();
        mScale *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        float xDiff = initialFocalPoints[0] - currentFocalPoints[0];
        float yDiff = initialFocalPoints[1] - currentFocalPoints[1];

        matrix.setScale(mScale, mScale, currentFocalPoints[0], currentFocalPoints[1]);
        matrix.postTranslate(xDiff, yDiff);
        mImageViewMain.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float startX = detector.getFocusX();
        float startY = detector.getFocusY();

        initialFocalPoints = new float[]{startX, startY};
        Matrix inverseTransformMatrix = new Matrix();
        if(matrix.invert(inverseTransformMatrix))
        inverseTransformMatrix.mapPoints(currentFocalPoints, initialFocalPoints);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        return;
    }
```

Is it possible to make `Imageview` wrap all the zoomed image? I tried many ways but still can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right, this is what's happening:  You are zooming in on a focal point, then when you are zooming out on a different focal point, you see blank space around the edge of the image because it isn't centered.

I had to deal with this in my custom pinch-zoom image view.  What needs to happen is that the bounds of the transformed image need to be checked against the bounds of the `ImageView` itself, and if any bound is within the `ImageView`, an extra translation needs to be added to correct for the blank space.

To do this, I used `Matrix.mapRect()` to give me a preview of what the image transform would look like.

These are properties, so you only allocate each `RectF` once:

```
        RectF imageRect = new RectF(0, 0, bitmap.getIntrinsicWidth(), bitmap.getIntrinsicHeight());

        RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, mImageViewMain.getWidth(), mImageViewMain.getHeight());

        RectF transform = new RectF();
```

Note that you can't do this until after everything has been measured and laid out.

Put the followin code in `onScale()` after `setScale()` and `postTranslate()` but before `mImageViewMain.setImageMatrix(matrix);`

```
        matrix.mapRect(transform, imageRect);  // dst, src

        // for this code to work, your matrix scaleX/Y can never be less that 1.0

        float xAdj = 0F;
        float yAdj = 0F;
        if (transform.left > 0) {  // blank space on left
            xAdj = - transform.left;
        } else if (transform.right < mImageViewMain.getWidth()) { // on right
            xAdj = mImageViewMain.getWidth() - transform.right;
        }

        if (transform.top > 0) { // blank space on top
            yAdj = - transform.top;
        } else if (transform.bottom < mImageViewMain.getHeight()) { // on bottom
            yAdj = mImageViewMain.getHeight() - transform.bottom;
        }

        matrix.postScale(xAdj, yAdj);
```

That code may not be exactly right, but you get the idea.  Use `matrix.mapRect()` to see if you're going to have blank spaces, then call `matrix.postScale()` to fix the blank spaces.

The part I left out of the code is that you have to put in some more fancy calculation because the aspect ratio of the image may not match the aspect ratio of the `ImageView`, so sometimes you *want* the bounds to be inside, but in that case you have to make the adjustment so that the image is centered.  It's just a lot of math.